# How to automatically click a hyperlink

Tags: vba, email, outlook, automation

I receive hundreds of emails a day and I would like to automatically click a hyperlink button in the email body and send the message that pops up.

When you manually click the button/hyperlink in the email body, it auto-generates a message with a token and then you have to click send. I'd like this to happen automatically.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub olItems2_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim olReply As MailItem
Set olReply = Item.Reply
If Not InStr(Item.Body, "XXXXX") > 0 Then 
    **''click "Deny" hyperlink**
    olReply.Send
    Item.UnRead = False
Else
    **''click "Approve" hyperlink button**
    olReply.Send
    Item.UnRead = False
End If
```

How do I click the hyperlinks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HTMLBody` property for extracting the actual URL and then use the following code:

```
Sub DoBrowse()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "your_url"
End Sub
```

Comment: So I managed to use code `Item.GetInspector.WordEditor.Hyperlinks(5).Follow` (the hyperlink I want to click is always the 5th one). If I run the code automatically, I get errors and the wrong hyperlink is followed. If I run it manually/step-by-step, it works fine. 
I basically need it to click the 4th of 5th hyperlink in the e-mail, which generates a new email item, then auto send that new email that gets generated from clicking the hyperlink.